# Does OOP encourages good caching, and thus good performance?

Tags: c++, performance, oop

I'm using Ogre3D, so I'm using several classes who inherits Ogre and OIS classes to make my project run.

I'm starting to have some problems, because I'm constantly in need to access variables from one singleton to tell it to another to do what I want, so I have this huge mass of getters/setters which bloat my project.

I know that keeping data at reach is important for performance, and OOP sort of encourages such practice by default since you keep variables you need inside your class, but at some point it feels like a huge constraint and I end up making some much initializations with all those constructors, it's pathetic.

My little ridiculous game will never requires that much resource, Ogre3D use OOP so it can do its job efficiently, it doesn't require me to use OOP to do my game.

I'm thinking about putting all my data into different struct to make everything public, and not care about encapsulation.

Will it have an impact on performance, despite its bad OOP design ?

Comment: "I'm starting to have some problems, because I'm constantly in need to access variables from one singleton to tell it to another to do what I want, so I have this huge mass of getters/setters which bloat my project." **Ouch.** At least you realize this is a bad design.

Comment: If you have all your state in one huge singleton, then you already have a bad OOP design...

Comment: I see no reason not to, if OOP is a hinderance don't bother with it. Make your life easier and use structs if you feel you can accurately describe things that way and remove the bloat of getters/setters. And no one ever said OOP was the "right" way to do it ;)

Comment: @oli: I don't have all my state in one singleton, even with 4 singleton, it's still too many. I need more interaction between those components, and encapsulation feels like a barrier. What is a good a good OOP design ?

Comment: The singleton pattern is really overused. You almost never want a singleton. As for OO design, I've enjoyed Allen Hollub's take on it. He's got a book _Hollub on Patterns_, and first article I read by him was [_Why Getter and Setter Methods are Evil_](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to improve your performance with caching, OOP is not a show stopper, but also not the perfect programming paradigm: It often suggests mutable states in your objects, e.g. setters, as you've mentioned, to simplify constructors. With mutable states, re-usability of the objects, and thus caching, becomes much more difficult. Therefore, try to **minimize mutability** (see e.g. [Josh Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 15).

That's why the **functional paradigm** is more suitable. But you can adopt it pretty well in classical OOP. Modern OOP languages (e.g. Scala, C#, C++11) are actually multi-paradigm and offer all features necessary for easy immutability and functional programming in general.

Comment: so all I have to do is create many lambdas and forget all my classes ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's as simple as functional programming -> performance.

Comment: @Oli: Yes, functional programming and performance are not proportional (e.g. mutability via var assignments are quite fast). But gokoon is interested in *caching*, and there functional programming has the above mentioned advantage...

Comment: @gokoon: My approach would be: try to program as immutable as possible. Added that into my post.

Comment: so in C++ by immutable you mean const ?

Comment: @gokoon: yes, with the correct type of const (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness). Another interesting pointer (from the pluggable type system domain): http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checkers-manual.html#igj-checker.

Comment: I'm not sure to well understand how important const is, and what does it tell to the compiler.

Comment: The wikipedia article and the ones it links to are quite good to read. An introductory article is http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html. My point was that immutable objects are better re-usable and hence cachable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a controller ("I'm constantly in need to access variables from one singleton to tell it to another to do what I want").  Typically events cause actions which require information about state.

If you think a bit more about the actors, messages and actions in the system you might begin to start to distribute the information around a bit into the classes which represent the various actors in the system.

There is no one way, but if you use OOP, it does take a certain amount of modelling effort.  Particularly the idea of state and who knows the state is not necessarily well suited to be stored in one (or more) giant singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies more in usage of singleton than OOP. OOP is all about data structure encapsulation. The way you actually store your data is up to you, the important thing is the interface and servcies provided by the classes. Singleton are just poor man's global variable that pretend they're OOP.

Drop singleton, write better OOP, performances will rise again.

Comment: I agree with everything but the last sentence.  There's not necessarily any correlation between OOP and performance.

Comment: it's just that if I need to interact with all my objects, that's the point ? I should just use a global namespace, and encapsulating when I can. For the rest, putting objects into objects is not a good idea if I need to use them in all my code.

Comment: @gokoon If you need to access everything everywhere that's because the design is bad. Code should be organized so it only has localized responsibilities. This isn't an easy thing to learn to do.

Comment: @Oli : the sentence is misleading. I was referring to the fact that there is no reason OOP cant deliver performance if done right and that the problem is merley the (ab)use of singleton. Sorry if it went out somehow wrong

Comment: @gokoon Singleton is always bad design. This means you have relationship between your object that you just pushed under the rug. Clarify the design and singleton disappear. I ve been using OOP in HPC context with no problem of performance since ages ...